# GFCI tr[pping with no outside load

Tags: gfci

my GFCI has started tripping.  nothing is plugged in.  What could be the problem?

Comment: Are there wires connected to the GFCI's LOAD terminals?  Also, does it trip immediately when the circuit is turned on at the breaker, or does it only trip intermittently?

Comment: Is this an outside outlet? Or are other outlets connected to this outside? In both cases if there is moisture in the outlets that are outside tripping the GFCI can happen. In-use or extra duty covers are required by today's code and they are a good idea. If moisture is your problem get a good metal extra duty or in-use cover and make sure to use the seal if moisture is the problem or this will happen again.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the circuit breaker and pop the covers off and pull it out.  Disconnect anything from the LOAD terminals, tape up the bare wires so they can't touch anything, and put it back in the wall.

Does it still trip?  It's a bad GFCI.

Does it stop tripping?  It's because whatever was connected to the LOAD terminals has a ground fault... Or the wiring to those things.  You will know what those things are, because they lost power when the GFCI tripped (and also when you disconnected them).  You will need to troubleshoot further by disconnecting one thing at a time until you have narrowed it down to one thing.